# Creating hive table using configuration file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know basic concepts of HIVE. My query is creating the hive table using the external configuration/schema file.

I know the basic query to create the hive table where we pass the column header and datatype in the create table statement . That is nothing but we hard code it.

But I wanted to create the hive table where it takes the column header and datatype from the external configuration file. Can it be done in Hive? It’s fine even we are supposed to write the unix shell script to achieve it but I’m not sure about it.

Below is the format of my configuration file :

Config.txt

```
    id,Integer(2),NOT NULL
    name,String(20)
    state,String(5),NOT NULL
    phone_no,Integer(4)
    gender,Char(1)
```

As of now i have created one .hql file where i have written the hive create table statement script and calling the .hql file in the bash script file.

Below are the .hql file and .sh file:

hiveQ.hql:

```
    create table goodrecs(
    id int,
    name string,
    state string,
    phone_no int,
    gender string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;
    LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hduser/Dataparse/goodrec' INTO TABLE goodrecs;
```

testscript.sh :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    hive -f hiveQ.hql
```

In hiveQ.hql i wanted column headers and datatype should come from the config.txt file.

How this can be done ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is very convenient to change config.txt to a standard hql file,use a map which turns types in config.txt to hive column type such as integer to int,char to string.

Comment: Hi, i didn't get changing config.txt to .hql file and then using map. Can you elaborate bit more.

Comment: must write a  script to do this task,no way to use hive directly

Comment: Ya, writing script is a better option but I'm not getting how to start with and even not able to visualize how script is going to talk to hive shell for creating table.